# What is the fastest method to map decision tree nodes to one-hot vectors?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

Consider the function `f` which takes decision-tree node parameters {-1,+1} and maps it to an one-hot vector [0,0,0,1] for example.

[image]

I think this will end up being one of the bottlenecks of a program I'm working on, so I'd like to know if anyone finds a faster way to map the parameters to the vector.

```
f<-function(h){
    # function takes as arguments:
    # an m-bit vector of potential split decisions (h)
    # function returns: 
    # an m+1-length one-hot indicator vector
    theta_vec = c(rep(0,length(h)+1))
    position = length(h)+1
    for(bit in seq(1,length(h),2)){
        if(h[bit]>0){
            position=position
        }
        else{
            position=position/2
        }
    }
    theta_vec[position]=1
    return(theta_vec)
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got a solution that runs in a quarter of the time. Are you able to refactor so that you use (0,1) instead of (-1,1); and use it as lists of rows instead of a vector? I find its easier to interpret when thinking about the problem, although the function below could be re-written to use a vector as input.

```
findPos <- function(h){

  # find number of rows from input
  N <- length(h)

  # go through and pick out the values in each tree that are valid based
  # on previous route
  out <- c(h[[1]], rep(0, N-1))
  for(i in 2:N){
    out[i] <- h[[i]][sum(out[i:(i-1)] * 2^(i-1)/(2^((i-1):1))) + 1]
  }

  # now find the final position in the bottom row and return as a vector
  out_pos <- sum(out * 2^N/(2^(1:N))) + 1
  full_vec <- rep(0, 2^N)
  full_vec[out_pos] <- 1

  return(full_vec)
}

# couple of e.gs
f(c(0,1,1))
findPos(list(0, c(1,1)))

f(c(1,1,1))
findPos(list(1, c(1,1)))

# works with larger trees
findPos(list(1, c(1,1), c(1,0,0,0)))

# check time using microbenchmark package
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "old" = {
    f(c(0,1,1))
  },
  "new" = {
    findPos(list(0, c(1,1)))
  }
)
```

Best
Jonny